# Match Two PCBs Layout and Dimension in EAGLE CAD

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, eaglecad, pcb-layers, cad

I want to create a PCB (name A) where I can put another PCB (name B)  on top of it using Autodesk EAGLE. I need to match the PCB B's pads position while designing PCB A.

Here's the picture of PCB B :

[image: PCB B]

In PCB A I have the same Con1 and Con2, and need to position them exactly as how Con1 and Con2 positioned in PCB B.

What I have tried select all / Group the PCB B and paste them in my PCB A.brd but got the following error :

[image: PCB A error]

I guess it's because I didn't put the schematic of PCB B on my PCB A's.sch
So I copy the PCB's schematic and paste them on my PCB A.sch, but when I get back to PCB A.brd, the PCB B appear unrouted, unlike the one that shown in first picture.

Please help me find the solution. My goals is only I could place Con1 and Con2 in my PCB A so that it's match the position of Con1 and Con2 on PCB B.

Thank you

Comment: for such a simple task, I would just measure the offset between say pin 1 in X and Y direction and manually offset them on your second project, you can add dimensions to both if you wish to double check, that or start with copying the absolute position values from one and entering them on the other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest and safest approach here is to simply note down the X-Y coordinate and rotation of the two connectors in the first board, and then simply apply the same coordinates and rotation to the corresponding parts on the second board.

You can do this by right clicking on the components origin, selecting properties, and it will tell you the coordinates. In the second board you can do the same but type in (or paste in) the new coordinates for the connectors.

---

I would additionally recommend locking the parts on both boards once placed in the correct locations to prevent accidentally moving them later on in the design process.

---

---

A more advanced technique would be to open up the .brd files in a text editor (they are just XML files), and change the coordinates with a simple copy paste. Be sure to have a backup of your eagle files before attempting this approach just in case something goes wrong.

You simply have to search for

```
<element name="CON1"
```

Or whatever the name is and you can change the `x` and `y` positions there. To change the rotation, either edit or add the `rot="R##"` attribute, where `##` is the angle of rotation. For parts on the back of the opposite side of the board, this would be `rot="MR##"`.

I would not recommend this for parts which have already been routed as this method will not move the routes. Additionally you'll need to run `ratsnest` once you reopen the board in eagle to update the airwires.

However this approach is quite useful for updating multiple parts quickly.